# Fenchel Duality in Prof. Bertsekas' lecture

Tags: functions, optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Please see [this link](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Chapter_1_NEW_ALG.pdf), p.39-41 (sufficient to answer my question), before (1.47) for detailed.

For convenience, the relevant part is shown as:

[image]

---

> I am confused in two things:

1. The conjugacy relation between the primal function $p$ and the dual function $q$.
2. How to derive (1.47)

Note: $Q(\mu) = \underset{u\in R^r}{u^T\mu - P(u)} = P^*(\mu)$

---

> My work:

1. The derivation is in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398283/conjugacy-relation-in-the-primal-and-dual-problem/1399049?noredirect=1#comment2851313_1399049). It seems we cannot say $p(u)=q^*(u)$
2. To (1.47), my derivation is:

a. The left-hand side of (1.47) can be written as (Fenchel duality framework)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&{\text{min}}
& & p(u)+P(Iu)\\
& \text{s.t.} & &  u \in R^r \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
b. It is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&{\text{min}}
& & p(u_1)+P(u_2)\\
& \text{s.t.} & &  u_1, u_2 \in R^r \\
&  & &  u_2=Iu_1 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} 
c. Form the dual function:
\begin{align*}
&\ \ \ \ \underset{u_1,u_2}{\text{inf}}\{p(u_1)+P(u_2)+\mu^T(u_2-u_1)\}\\ &= \underset{u_1}{\text{inf}}\{p(u_1)-\mu^T u_1\} + \underset{u_2}{\text{inf}}\{P(u_2)+\mu^T u_2\}\\ &= -\underset{u_1}{\text{sup}}\{\mu^T u_1-p(u_1)\} - \underset{u_2}{\text{inf}}\{(-\mu)^T u_2 - P(u_2)\} \\ &= -p^*(\mu) - P^*(-\mu)\end{align*}
d. Form the dual problem:
\begin{align*}
& \underset{\mu}{\text{sup}} \{-p^*(\mu) - P^*(-\mu)\} \end{align*}

I do not know the following steps to obtain the right-hand side of (1.47).

Comment: This question is a disguissed version of at least two other questions here on SE, one of which is http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399049/168758 ;)  It'd be nice if you could stick to one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually easy. Let's do it from first principles. First observe that
\begin{eqnarray}
\underset{\mu \ge 0}{\text{sup }}\mu^T(g(x)-u) = \begin{cases}0, &\mbox{ if }g(x) \le u,\\+\infty, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

Now,
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
\text{LHS of 1.47} &= \underset{u \in \mathbb{R}^r}{\text{inf }}p(u) + P(u) = \underset{u \in \mathbb{R}^r}{\text{inf }}\underset{x \in X, g(x) \le u}{\text{inf }}f(x) + P(u) \\
&= \underset{u \in \mathbb{R}^r}{\text{inf }}\underset{x \in X}{\text{inf }}f(x) + \underset{\mu \ge 0}{\text{sup }}\mu^T(g(x)-u) + P(u)\\
&=\underset{\mu \ge 0}{\text{sup }}\underbrace{\underset{x \in X}{\text{inf }}f(x) + \mu^Tg(x)}_{q(\mu)} + \underbrace{\underset{u \in \mathbb{R}^r}{\text{inf }}P(u) - \mu^Tu}_{-Q(\mu)}\\
&=\underset{\mu \ge 0}{\text{sup }}q(\mu) - Q(\mu) = \text{RHS of 1.47}
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}

This should hopefully answer your question.

Comment: Thanks!  The key step is that principle. However, I use the step similar in page 11 possibly misguided  by the author and get stuck there.